# make changes in page content before load in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, cms

I want to make changes in cms page's content dynamically before page load on front-end.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As every request is processed through a controller in Magento we'll start from `Mage_Cms_PageController` where we see that the `cms/page` helper actually renders the page.

This is done in the method `_renderPage`. In this method we'll find the Event `cms_page_render` on line 107. This event gives you, among other objects, the `page` object.

This object contains all the data of your page. Now you can observe this event from your custom build extension by adding it to the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
    <events>
      <cms_page_render>
        <observers>
          <your_extension_cms_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Your_Extension_Model_Csm_Observer</class>
            <method>changeContent</method>
          </your_extension_cms_observer>
        </observers>
      </cms_page_render>     
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

This will call the class `Your_Extension_Model_Csm_Observer`, method `changeContent` which should look something like this

```
class Your_Extension_Model_Csm_Observer
{

    public function changeContent($observer)
    {
      $event = $observer->getEvent();
      $cms_page = $event->getPage();   

      [...]
    your code goes here
      [...]

      return $this;
    }
}
```

For more info about observers check this [Wiki page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)