# How do I modify Magento rendered page before it's displayed?

Tags: product, module, magento-1, frontend, cms

I am trying to modify the rendered page content before it's displayed to the user. I would like to do this in my custom module.

So far, I have tried hooking into the [`cms_page_render`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6874/make-changes-in-page-content-before-load-in-magento) event but:

- it does not work for product pages
- it doesn't hold the final HTML; it still has Magento templating tags

How do I go about modifying the rendered page content right before it's displayed to the user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to change the content of a page using in observer means you need to do something with layout of the page. There are lot of events available to alter the layout of magento. To select the right one is simply depends upon where you need to change the output and conditions.

If you classify Magento events, we can see that, there are some general events, specific events and there are some dynamic events too. **General events** means events that get called in every page load request. **Specific events** means events that get called during some special occasions, means during some specific page loads. **Dynamic events** are kind of dynamic events. Difference is their names are dynamic, it will change depend upon which module processing.

In this case, you just want to change the content part. But there are many events that allow us to change the layout of the requested page. You can use these events `controller_action_layout_load_before` or `controller_action_layout_load_after` to change the layout structure directly. These events are specific for layout alterations. Now if you want to change the blocks, add blocks, change the template that is using by a block etc, you can use `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before` or `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` events. Now ..

**If you need to directly alter the html content of a page, you can use `core_block_abstract_to_html_after`.**  Here the html content of the page is passing through `transport` object. So if you observe on this event, then in your observer you can get the html content as like this

```
public function someFunction($observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();

    //if you trying to chang product view page content.
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View) {
        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $html = $transport->getHtml();
        $html .= 'We need to append something here';
        $transport->setHtml($html);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! What are the benefits of using `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` over `controller_action_postdispatch`?

Comment: Does not work for me - `getTransport` returns `null`.

Comment: Transport object is populated for `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` event.

Comment: @GinoPane Yes and that is what I explained above. Please re-read my answer

Comment: @RajeevKTomy Yep, sorry, now I see.

Comment: How we call model observer to get html into phtml file..

Comment: Another reason to use `controller_action_layout_load_before` or similar events that work with templates instead of general `controller_action_postdispatch` or `controller_action_predispatch` is that latter will fire on any request, including AJAX requests. This can affect whole website performance considerably. Using general `controller_action_predispatch` event should be last option, and only if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that instead of using `cms_page_render`, use the  `controller_action_layout_load_before` which is triggered `just before rendering layout`.

It is triggered on `both admin and frontend`, if you need to be specific, e.g.  `frontend` then you need specify it in `frontend events` of the XML.

Then, you can use these two parameters:

```
'action'=>$this, 'layout'=>$this->getLayout()
```

**example XML:**

```
 <frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <observers>
                <customer_is_logged_in_observer>
                    <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                </customer_is_logged_in_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_load_before>
    </events>
 </frontend>
```

In the observer:

```
  public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
  { // current layout
      $layout=$observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
      $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
         ->addHandle('newhandler'));
  }
```

And if you need put cms page condition, then put `condition on` of current controller and module.

**Using below code:**

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName(); // return controller name
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName(); // return action name
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); // return routes name
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName(); // return module name
```

just like cms page:

```
public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
{
    if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='page' && Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName()='cms')
    {

        // current layout
        $layout=$observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
         ->addHandle('newhandler'));
    }
}
```

**In this observer, you can change layout (and other stuff) before rendering layout.**

**edit: inject and edit block**

```
$block = $layout->createBlock(
  'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
  'my_block_name_here',
  array('template' => 'activecodeline/developer.phtml')
);
$layout->getBlock('content')->append($block);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Is there a way to programatically process the HTML instead of using a handler?

Comment: here you can edit a block  programmatically  and inject new block.

Comment: How to replace add to cart button to pre order button text using above observer