# Adding suffix to head title on all pages for magento 1

Tags: layout, magento-1, header, page-title

What's the best way to add some text (e.g. [staging], [dev], ...) to the end of the header title on all pages? I'm thinking of some "layout" event to listen to where I can:

```
$observer->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($originalTitle . ' [staging]');
```

But which one?

Answer (score 2):

To add suffix to your store title tags go to `System > Configuration > Design > Html Head`.Here you can see `"Title Suffix"` you can give your title suffix here. Which will add your given suffix on all pages on website after your title.

Answer (score 0):

`core_block_abstract_to_html_after` should work - see [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34225/how-do-i-modify-magento-rendered-page-before-its-displayed) for more details.